# Is it a good way to design no-sql database?

Tags: database-design, nosql, key-value-store

I have big enough experience with the relations' databases, but want to try no-SQL one (key-value). And have concocted a task for this. And this is another link shorter with grouping on users, campaigns and stats. And it must works in high-load of course =)

Uses cases:

```
1. Generate short link
1.1. User is not logged, without a campaign.
  Put a pair to the bucket LINKS, don't put to USERS and CAMPAIGNS buckets.
1.2. User is logged, without a campaign.
  Put the pair to LINKS, update a counter in the bucket USERS, don't put to CAMPAIGN bucket.
1.3. User is logged and campaign is created.
  Put/update pairs to all the buckets.
```

```
2. Get statistics.
2.1. Get all links and its stats by user (must be logged).
2.2. Get all links and its stats by campaign (must be logged).
2.3. Get stats by short url (must be logged).
```

```
3. Redirect to a long url by short one (no matter logged user or not).
```

---

How I'm solving this task with a relations DB. Four tables:

- users (id, name);
- campaigns (owner_id, id, name);
- urls (shortURL, campaign_id, long_url);
- stats (shortURL, get_counter, created_at, last_access_at).

Of course, I've skipped the indexes and denormalization here.

And now I'm thinking how to implements this in no-SQL DB (kv).

Legend: (b) - bucket/sub bucket, (k) - key, (v) - value

```
/.
 |--- (b) USERS --- (k) user_id
 |              --- (v) { "name": "User", "settings": {}, "stats": {"link_count": 1}, "links": ["a","b"]}
 |--- (b) LINKS --- (k) short_link
 |              --- (v) { "long_link": "https://example.com", "stats" : {"counter": 1, "created_at": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z, "last_access_at": "2019-01-01T00:00:01Z"}}
 |--- (b) CAMPAIGNS --- (b) USER_ID --- (k) campaign_id
 |                                  --- (v) { "name": "campaign", "links": ["a", "b"]}
```

Is it a correct way to solve it?

2.1. Gets all links from USERS bucket by user_id from links array, then get all stats by getting stats by short_url one by one.

2.2. The same as the above. Gets links from CAMPAIGNS.USER_ID.links array and obtains statistics one by one from the LINKS bucket.

Or the design of the kv database is total wrong?